# jQuery popups effect not working in IE but working on other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, popup

I'm having problems with a jQuery effect in IE.  However, they work properly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

I've searched in the forums, but I can't find the problem.

The website is http://www.voces.org.es

The function that does not work in IE is:

1. A function for popups:

   ```
       $(document).ready(function() {
   //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a #

   $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
       var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
       var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

       //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
       var query= popURL.split('?');
       var dim= query[1].split('&');
       var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

       //Fade in the Popup and add close button
       $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="http://voces.org.es/wp-content/themes/voces/img/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

       //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 80px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
       var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
       var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

       //Apply Margin to Popup
       $('#' + popID).css({
           'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
           'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
       });

       //Fade in Background
       $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
       $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies
       return false;
   });

   //Close Popups and Fade Layer
   $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
       $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
           $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
       });
       return false;
   });
   ```

   });

I've fought my way throught this, my first web project, but I really can't solve this issue.  I would appreciate help here.

Comment: _"does not work"_ is a wholly inadequate problem description.

Comment: Seems Jquery is loading but the function doesn´t trigger the popup.  Would like to explain the problem better but i really don´t know what the issue is

Comment: For starters, you have not included the steps to reproduce the problem or which IE versions.

Comment: Doesn´t work in IE7 or IE8 but haven´t tried on IE6.  Not sure what you meen by reproduce the problems, i´ve posted a link to the website where the popups are not working.  I´m really sorry i cant explain myself better, im new to programming and ive fought all the way throught my first project reading in forums but cant really see where the problem is here

Comment: Your site is not in English so how am I supposed to know how to invoke this popup?  Just tell us what to click.

Comment: sorry :)  The link you are supposes to click is the bottom left link in the footer which reads "politica de privacidad"

Answer (score 0):

1)  Before going further, fix all [HTML Validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://voces.org.es/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  I'm getting some console errors related to stray tags.

Surround any JavaScript within the `<body>` with `//<![CDATA[` & `//]]>` tags to stop HTML Validation from parsing your JS code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    //<![CDATA[

        //  your jQuery/JavaScript

    //]]>
</script>
```

2)  Make sure you're using the latest version of jQuery.  You are using version 1.4.1 which is more than a year old.  It's up to 1.7 now and a lot has changed.

3)  Quote OP comment:  *"Doesn't work in IE7 or IE8 but haven't tried on IE6."*  -  If possible, forget about IE6 and focus on IE9.

4)  If it still does not work, try a jQuery Lightbox plugin (proven to work with IE) for the modal pop-up instead.  [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) and [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) are solid choices.

Comment: Great, sounds like a good place to start.  I´ll start trying your suggestions right away and keep you posted on the results.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Just putting the //<![CDATA[   //]]> made everything work.  Thanks Sparky672!